# Insert a running number in textfile in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text-files

I would like to add a running number inside a textfile but it must be in specific column. etc: line 1, column 15.

original file : it has data name,profession,birthdate,status

```
john   teacher 1988 married
marcel engineer1976 single
emi    professo1975 married
```

convert file:insert running number between birthdate and status

```
john   teacher 1988 D001married
marcel engineer1976 D002single
emi    professo1975 D003married
```

note : every data start at their own specific column. name start at column 1, profession start at column 7,birthday start at column 15 and status start at column 20.

how do I do this using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what `String.Insert()` is for.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>
{
    "john   teacher 1988 married",
    "marcel engineer1976 single",
    "emi    professo1975 married"
};

Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine();

int runningNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    data[i] = data[i].Insert(20, String.Format("D{0:000}", runningNumber));
    runningNumber++;
}

Console.WriteLine("After: ");
data.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Results:

```
Before:
john   teacher 1988 married
marcel engineer1976 single
emi    professo1975 married

After:
john   teacher 1988 D001married
marcel engineer1976 D002single
emi    professo1975 D003married
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each row of the text and run something like this on each line:

```
const int STATUS_START_COLUMN_NUM = 19;

line = line.Substring(0,STATUS_START_COLUMN_NUM - 1) + "D" + String.Format("{0:000}",i) + line.Substring(STATUS_START_COLUMN_NUM);
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample solution that makes use of `StringBuilder` and `TextWriter` with the use of `string.Format()` and additional functionality `Truncate` to get the proper length of string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplicationStringBuilder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
            john   teacher 1988 married
            marcel engineer1976 single
            emi    professo1975 married
            */

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -7}{1, -8}{2, -5}{3}", Truncate("john", 6), Truncate("teacher", 8), 1988, Truncate("married", 7)));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -7}{1, -8}{2, -5}{3}", Truncate("marcel", 6), Truncate("engineer", 8), 1976, Truncate("single", 7)));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0, -7}{1, -8}{2, -5}{3}", Truncate("emi", 6), Truncate("professor", 8), 1975, Truncate("married", 7)));

            string s = sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            //Write to file
            using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText("C:\\test.txt"))
            {
                tw.Write(s);
                tw.Flush();
                tw.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("File written to C:\\test.txt"); ;
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static public string Truncate(string value, int max)
        {
            return value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, max));
        }
    }
}
```

What happens here are the following:

- Truncate each string you passed on `Truncate` function to get only the string within the given maximum value
- Pass each value to `string.Format()` padding each item with the blank spaces needed
- Build all the string via `StringBuilder` and convert it to a `string`
- Create a text file and assign it `TextWriter` filling it with the `string` that was built previously